# Skip split_and_strip_files function for a specific binay or recipe

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I need to include a binary in my image. But the do_package execute the python function `split_and_strip_files`. The striped image has some bugs that are not present in the original image.

I want to skip this function only for this binary or recipe.

I use a simple recipe like this one:

```
SUMMARY = "Software"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "<binary url>"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "<binary md5>"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "\
    libedit \
"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/<binary file>  ${D}${bindir}
}
```

I tried `INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"`, but it apply to the entire project and the size of the image generated is too big.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have forgotten to clean the project because I got the desired result by putting `INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"` in the recipe once again.

Sorry for the false problem